# esp8266 post return error code 301. What can be the issue?

Tags: esp8266

I created a system that should post some data to a database, i use a file that receive the data, in php format, as followed on tutorial https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-esp8266-mysql-database-php/.
My credentials are correct, but the response from http post request is 301. I use Hostinger for hosting the DB.

```
const char* ssid       = "MY_NETWORK";  //network
const char* password   = "MY_PASS";   //pass
const char* serverName = "http://MY_WEBSSITE/post-esp-data.php";   //webserver receiveng page
String apiKeyValue     = "MY_API_KEY";      //api key
void loop() 
{
 //some code
            if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED)
                {
                  HTTPClient http;
                  // http.setFollowRedirects(HTTPC_FORCE_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS);
                  http.begin(wifiClient, serverName);
                  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                                       
                  String httpRequestData = "api_key=" + apiKeyValue +  "";  //plus some data
                  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData); 
                  Serial.print("httpResponseCode ");
                  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
                  http.end();
                }
          // some other code
}
```

Do you have any ideea how to fix it?

I try to apply some fix for server redirect, but might not be correct

Comment: is `wifiClient` WiFiClientSecure?

Comment: You are trying to access a https (secure) website with non-secure http request. See [http 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Comment: Thank you for your support. it was a ssl certificate that generates me that issue. only yesterday i had time to manage this issue.